Is there the concept 'apatreya' (unfit for getting charity) in Hinduism?
I read the following on the internet but had no luck finding the word 'apatreya' on the internet:

In Hinduism, as per Dharmashastras, Puranas and several other
scriptures, charity should only be given to brahmanas learned in Vedas
and nobody else. Every other person, no matter how poor they are, are
'apatreya' (unfit for getting charity).

Is the above true &/or accurate, or otherwise have some basis for relevance? If so, please kindly explain was should be known about the concept of 'apatreya' (unfit for getting charity)?

निन्दितेभ्यो धनादानं वाणिज्यं शूद्रसेवनं । अपात्रीकरणं ज्ञेयम - Accepting money from despicable people, engaging in trade, serving sūdras are known to cause (in a brāhmaṇa) apātrahood(i.e unfit to be invited in sacred rites) - Agnipurāṇa:168

Thank you. What is meant by "serving" sudras? What type/types of service does this refer to?

@Dhammadhatu While 17th century scholar Kāmalākara Bhaṭṭa of Vāraṇasī quoting the opinion of 15th century Bengali scholar Śūlapāṇa that brāhmaṇas can accept śūdras as yajamāna, Śūlapāṇi describes servitude as 3 types - sexual (marrying off brāhmaṇa girl to a śūdra man), oral (receiving knowledge; both secular & religious, from a śūdra's mouth) & economic (accepting wages from a śūdra for a living).

Thank you  অনু . Therefore it appears the term "serving sūdras" does not apply to a Brahmin giving economic charity to a poor non-Brahmin person. Instead, as you said, "serving sudras" refers to working for a sudra. In Buddhism, the Buddha also taught a Brahmin should marry a Brahmin.
